# Jquery: Open a new HTML windows when button is click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron

1) I'm trying to get this working just for testing purpose, can you help me out?

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
   var name = 'Juan';
   var pass = '123456';
   $('#boton').click( function () {
    if ($('#name') === name && $('#pass') === pass ) {
        windows.open('mainScreen.html'):
    } 
    else {
        alert("WRONG PASSWORD");
    }

    });
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing `#name` and `#pass` are text boxes?

Comment: You can't compare jQuery objects to strings. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Shouldn't you be comparing the value of those elements rather than comparing the actual element? `.val()` For testing/debugging I would recommend you open the browser console and use `console.log();` to check the return/result/value of something and you will  also be able to check for syntax errors

Comment: `windows.open` is wrong. Use `window.open` instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:-

Here is working demo: https://output.jsbin.com/qitedoq

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function (){   
    var name = 'Juan';
    var pass = '123456';    
    $('#boton').click( function () {
      if ($('#name').val() === name && $('#pass').val() === pass ) {
          window.open('https://www.google.com/');
      } else {
          alert("WRONG PASSWORD");
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Username"> <br />
<input type="text" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
<button id="boton">Click Here</button>
</body>
</html>
```